# Delete via double click to jQuery cloned helper object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to delete a cloned helper object by double-clicking on it.

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.animate({
                width: 200,
                height: 200
            });
        },
        cursorAt: {left:50, top:50}
    })
        .on('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
        $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable({cursor:'move'}).resizable());});

});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/armidia/vfn7ypmo/).  Drag the red square to create a clone.  I now wish to delete the clone via a double-click but all attempts have failed thus far.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete an element we just need to use `$(this).remove()`. try the following code to make it work:

```
    .on('dragstop', function (event, ui) {
    $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().addClass('removable').draggable({
        cursor: 'move'
    }).resizable());

    $('.removable').dblclick(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vfn7ypmo/4/)

Comment: That's what I had...almost!  I had the delete call outside of the draggable function.  Many thanks!